# Finitistic dimension via tilting modules

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

is the following true (all algebras and modules are assumed to be finite dimensional):
The finitistic dimension of an algebra is equal to the supremum of projective dimensions of tilting modules?
It is true for Gorenstein algebras, since there D(A) is a tilting module.

Comment: It is also true if the category of modules with finite global dimension is contravariantly finite, in particular it is true for finite representation type.

Comment: Yes, I also found that in http://www.jstor.org/stable/3072902?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents.